# What does (Put the Two together) mean?

Tags: exam-questions

What is the meaning of Put the Two together in the paragraph below?

> Making loans and fighting poverty are normally two of the least glamorous pursuits around, but remarkably enough **put the two together**, and you have an economic innovation that has become not just popular but downright chic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it means, "if you do them both." The idiom, "put the two together and," suggests images of combining ingredients in a recipe, or maybe mixing reagents for some chemical reaction. It always carries the meaning of, "the result (what follows the *and*) is not what it otherwise would have been."